# VS SQL Server Object Explorer takes forever to load nodes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

VS 2013 SQL Server object Explorer connected to a SQL Azure database, trying to open table/column/key info takes 30seconds-2min.  I can open it in SSMS in ~2 seconds.  It's not a large database (just starting, 30 or so tables so far).

Any idea why this is so slow in the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS?

(I'm actually not sure if this Object Explorer is part of SSDT or not - if it matters, SSDT version is 12.0.50318.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSDT loads all SQL objects when you open start the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS. Once you have loaded it, loading any additional nodes under the same tree shouldn't take that long.

That said, Microsoft is looking at performance improvements in the near future for the Object Explorer in SSDT.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of SSDT with Azure SQL and expanding nodes like "Databases" and "Logins" takes 5-10 seconds. I see no reason for the delay if it's enumerating all objects on load.

Comment: We're now in the near future (one year since your answer) and the performance improvements haven't arrived yet. It seems that everything on Microsoft takes longer than they promise...